# slide animation ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I want to create a kind of slider with nganimate and with an ng-repeat. Basecally there is a content with two button (next and previous) in order to slide left or right.

```
        <div class="previous" ng-click="getPreviousTrainingsWeek($index)" ></div>


    <div class="content"  ng-repeat=" week in weeks | limitTo:1 " >
       <div >
            {{$index}}
           Semaine du {{week | formatDateWithoutDay}}
       </div> 
    </div>


    <div class="next" ng-click="getNextTrainingsWeek($index)"></div>
```